# Why unable to parse a string | Rust

Tags: parsing, types, rust

I am making decimal to binary conversion program. Why am i unable to parse a string into a number? `binary_vec[i]` is a `character`. I applied `to_string()` method to convert it into a string because `parse()` doesn't apply to a character, but it still giving me an error.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut binary = String::new();
    println!("Enter a decimal: ");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut binary)
        .ok()
        .expect("Couldn't read line");
    println!("{}",to_decimal(binary));

}

fn to_decimal(mut binary_str:String) -> String {
    let mut binary_no: u32 = binary_str.trim().parse().expect("invalid input");
    if binary_no == 0 {
        format!("{}",binary_no)
                } 
    else {
        let mut bits = String::new();
        let mut binary_vec: Vec<char> = binary_str.chars().collect();
        let mut result = 0;
        let mut i = 0;
        while i <=binary_str.len()-2{
            let mut result = result + (binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2^(i as u32));
            i = i +1;
        }
        format!("{}",result)
        }
}
```

Result:

```
 Compiling sixteen v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Muhammad.3992348\Desktop\rust\hackathon\sixteen)
warning: unused variable: `bits`
  --> src\main.rs:19:17
   |
19 |         let mut bits = String::new();
   |                 ^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_bits`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

warning: unused variable: `result`
  --> src\main.rs:24:21
   |
24 |             let mut result = result + (binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2^(i as u32));
   |                     ^^^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_result`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:13:15
   |
13 | fn to_decimal(mut binary_str:String) -> String {
   |               ----^^^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_mut)] on by default

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |     let mut binary_no: u32 = binary_str.trim().parse().expect("invalid input");
   |         ----^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:19:13
   |
19 |         let mut bits = String::new();
   |             ----^^^^
   |             |
   |             help: remove this `mut`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:20:13
   |
20 |         let mut binary_vec: Vec<char> = binary_str.chars().collect();
   |             ----^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             help: remove this `mut`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:21:13
   |
21 |         let mut result = 0;
   |             ----^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             help: remove this `mut`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:24:17
   |
24 |             let mut result = result + (binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2^(i as u32));
   |                 ----^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 help: remove this `mut`

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.04s
     Running `target\debug\sixteen.exe`
Enter a decimal:
100
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src\libcore\result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\sixteen.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

Edit:
I have input 100 and I expect to get 4 at output.

Comment: What input are you giving when you run the program? What output do you expect for that input?

Comment: @User I have input 100 and I expect to get 4 at output.

Comment: With that input, I don't get the panic. Instead I get 0 (and I can see where that comes from). Can you confirm that entering 100 makes your program panic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with the code as written. The good news is that you can fix most of the problems by listening to the compiler warnings!

```
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
19 |         let mut bits = String::new();
   |                 ^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_bits`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
```

This tells you that the variable `bits` isn't used after this declaration. If you intend to use it later, you can just comment it out for now.

```
warning: unused variable: `result`
  --> src/main.rs:24:21
   |
24 |             let mut result = result + (binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2^(i as u32));
   |                     ^^^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_result`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
```

This is the big one. This tells us that the variable `result` is unused. But wait! we're using it right here! Nope! Actually, by using `let mut` here, we're making a new variable and shadowing the old one. What you want is to instead overwrite the old value. Simply change `let mut result = ...` to `result = ...`.

Now if we run the program again and input `100`, we'll get an output of `5`. This still doesn't seem right, but we still have a few warnings to fix, so let's come back to this.

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
13 | fn to_decimal(mut binary_str:String) -> String {
   |               ----^^^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_mut)] on by default
```

If we aren't going to mutate the input string, we shouldn't make it mutable. Just remove the `mut`. Same for the other two warnings (lines 14 and 20).

Alright! Now we can run the program without any warnings. However, there are some more advanced lints we can run using `cargo clippy`. If you don't have clippy installed yet, you can install it with `rustup install component clippy`.

Now we have a few more warnings to take care of.

```
warning: operator precedence can trip the unwary
  --> src/main.rs:24:32
   |
24 |             result = result + (binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2^(i as u32));
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider parenthesizing your expression: `(binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2) ^ (i as u32)`
   |
   = note: #[warn(clippy::precedence)] on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#precedence
```

Uh oh. Clippy is telling us that the precedence rules indicate that `*` is evaluated before `^`. That's not what we'd expect from multiplication and exponents. It turns out that `^` is *not* the exponent operator. Instead, it's the bitwise xor. If we want powers of a number, we can use the `pow` method, so replace `2 ^ (i as u32)` with `2.pow(i as u32)`. This will cause a compiler error with the message `` error[E0689]: can't call method `pow` on ambiguous numeric type `{integer}` ``. Ok. We can make the numeric type unambiguous using a suffix. Change it to `2_u32.pow(i as u32)`.

We can fix the other three warnings that Clippy gives us just by using the suggestion. After that, Clippy gives one more warning, which also is fixed with just the suggestion.

Before we continue, let's make our code a bit prettier by running `cargo fmt`. Finally, the code looks like this:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut binary = String::new();
    println!("Enter a decimal: ");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut binary)
        .expect("Couldn't read line");
    println!("{}", to_decimal(binary));
}

fn to_decimal(binary_str: String) -> String {
    let binary_no: u32 = binary_str.trim().parse().expect("invalid input");
    if binary_no == 0 {
        format!("{}", binary_no)
    } else {
        //let mut bits = String::new();
        let binary_vec: Vec<char> = binary_str.chars().collect();
        let mut result = 0;
        let mut i = 0;
        while i <= binary_str.len() - 2 {
            result += binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() * 2_u32.pow(i as u32);
            i += 1;
        }
        format!("{}", result)
    }
}
```

We fixed two bugs and cleaned up the code only using compiler warnings and basic tools! Pretty good, eh? But now if we input `100`, our output is `1`. That isn't right. Let's add some debug statements to see if we can see what's going on.

```
result += dbg!(binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap()) * dbg!(2_u32.pow(i as u32));
```

If we run it now, here's what we get.

```
Enter a decimal: 
100
[src/main.rs:22] binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() = 1
[src/main.rs:22] 2u32.pow(i as u32) = 1
[src/main.rs:22] binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() = 0
[src/main.rs:22] 2u32.pow(i as u32) = 2
[src/main.rs:22] binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() = 0
[src/main.rs:22] 2u32.pow(i as u32) = 4
1
```

We can see that it's parsing the digits correctly: `binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap()` is `1`, then `0`, then `0`. The powers of 2 look fine too. The problem here is that it's backwards! We want the left digit to be multiplied with the *highest* power of 2. Let me note that this is the part of the code where you're the least idiomatic. It's much better to use, at the very least, a `for` loop for this kind of thing. Iterators would be even better if you can manage it.

In any case, we can reverse the order by making our powers go from `binary_str.len() - 2` down to `0` instead of the other way around. Thus, we can change the code to

```
while i <= binary_str.len() - 2 {
    result += dbg!(binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap()) * dbg!(2_u32.pow((binary_str.len() - 2 - i) as u32));
    i += 1;
}
```

We get

```
Enter a decimal: 
100
[src/main.rs:22] binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() = 1
[src/main.rs:22] 2u32.pow((binary_str.len() - 2 - i) as u32) = 4
[src/main.rs:22] binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() = 0
[src/main.rs:22] 2u32.pow((binary_str.len() - 2 - i) as u32) = 2
[src/main.rs:22] binary_vec[i].to_string().parse::<u32>().unwrap() = 0
[src/main.rs:22] 2u32.pow((binary_str.len() - 2 - i) as u32) = 1
4
```

so we see that the powers are correctly reversed from 4 down to 1. And our answer is finally correct! Test it on a few more inputs and try to find some edge cases. There are still some more bugs to find. Once you're happy with your code, take out the debug statements.

Comment: Holy. You've done what I was too lazy for :D and you've done a really good job. Get my upvote!

Comment: That's an incredible answer, teaching the OP to fish and introducing them to further tools (clippy, `dbg!`) along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually try to fix the code, but this one just seems way to convoluted.

Here is a simpler solution:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut binary = String::new();
    println!("Enter a decimal: ");

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut binary)
        .expect("Couldn't read line");

    match to_decimal(binary) {
        Some(num) => println!("{}", num),
        None => println!("Not a binary!")
    }
}

fn to_decimal(binary_str:String) -> Option<i64> {
    let binary_str = binary_str.trim();

    let mut out_num = 0;
    for c in binary_str.chars() {
        match c {
            '0' => out_num = out_num * 2,
            '1' => out_num = out_num * 2 + 1,
            _ => return None
        }
    }

    Some(out_num)
}
```